# Swift - stopAnimating() - must be used from main thread only

Tags: swift, animation, dispatch-queue

I have a succession of tasks that have to be performed in sequence, so they are corralled by DispatchQueue. To inform the user that they are chugging away I start the activity icon. But how do I stop if off the main thread?

Logically what I am trying to achieve is:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()    
   self.activityIcon.startAnimating()

   DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.bigTask1()   
   }

   DispatchQueue.main.async {
      self.bigTask2()  
      self.activityIcon.stopAnimating() 
   }
}
```

This obviously generates the runtime error: " `UIActivityIndicatorView.stopAnimating()` must be used from main thread only".

Putting the `stopAnimating()` in the main queue turns it on and off so fast no one will ever see it.

What is the approved way call functions like this off the `main` queue?

Many thanks. P.s. I have read answers of similar questions on SO but don't quite get them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do big task in default `background queue`, and when the big task completes then simply get the `main` queue and perfom any UI Updates.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()

   self.activityIcon.startAnimating()

   DispatchQueue.global().async {
      self.someBigTask()

      DispatchQueue.main.async {
         self.activityIcon.stopAnimating()
      }
   }

}
```

Hope you will find this helpful.